# Has there been a recent change in the "interesting" order?

Tags: discussion, interesting-page

I've noticed that a couple of questions, latest activity 1 and 2 hours ago, seem to be stuck near the top of my `Interesting` list. The tags I follow have a lot of activity so I'm unsure why these are not dropping down. Most of the others at the top have activity from just a few minutes ago.

The first time I noticed, they were stuck at positions 2 and 4. A few times since then I've noticed something stuck at 2. The questions had tags that I follow, but so did many others that didn't get stuck.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090951/how-do-i-create-another-top-level-window-in-wtl?_6f7f76dd=true

[New allocates too much memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089636/new-allocates-too-much-memory?_6f7f76dd=true)

Comment: There was a beta test for selected random users a while ago, maybe it's back. Looking for the link... can't find right now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't resist... but; *That's eeeeen-teresting...*

Comment: I've seen this problem too.  It's been around for quite a while, in spite of Andrew's sneer.  It does tend to resolve itself after an hour or two and strikes rarely.  Never found enough of a diagnostic to bring it up as a question.  That code is a livin' breathin' thing.

Comment: @UphillLuge is right. About my sneer! oh; and that the code needs some breath mints. as do I.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm still seeing the effect this evening, although a different set of questions are now stuck.

Comment: seriously, though; those posts you linked here... they are examples of "old" posts which erroneously show as recent?

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I hate to call them "old" since they are still from today; they're just a lot higher up in the list than I expect them to be. The first link was stuck at position #2 for at least an hour and I got really sick of seeing it.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue: http://i.stack.imgur.com/shlnf.png Possibly (un)relevant information: I've favorited the [tag:google-chrome-extensions] tag (attached to these questions), and I've recently got a [gold tag badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2854/google-chrome-extension?userid=938089) for it.

Comment: My frontpage has updated again, it seems that three slots (2nd, 4th and 6th) are always filled with the most recently active questions from the google-chrome-extensions tag. @MarkRansom How does your list look like?

Comment: @RobW the first time I noticed, they were stuck at positions 2 and 4. A few times since then I've noticed something stuck at 2. The questions had tags that I follow, but so did many others that didn't get stuck.

Comment: @RobW found the dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174679/152859 can you please flag this one, ask to refund the bounty and put it there instead if you're still interesting to get updated answer?

Comment: @Mark the answer is in the linked post, the change is still in A/B testing meaning it still appears only for randomly selected users and there's no way to opt in or out of this.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - This seems to be a different issue. Here it is specifically slots 2,4 and 6. [This is a newer duplicate though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193690/145673)

Comment: @MartinSmith nope, as this is still ongoing I'm 99% sure they just test different ways. Hopefully commenting there might bring Nick to confirm this.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Well if it is deliberate I hope they abandon it. I've had three not especially interesting questions stuck in those slots for a couple of hours now. I don't need to keep seeing them.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree, so far this had been going on without much attention maybe time to call the team out and ask for details, where it stands and in "our" case, ask to abort it altogether though small chances for that.

Comment: Also worth to mention that at least for me it's causing the homepage to load in over two seconds where it used to load in less than a second before, about 500% slower.

Comment: See also: [SO cache going nuts — or do I need a lot of sleep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174679/so-cache-going-nuts-or-do-i-need-a-lot-of-sleep) for a historical occurrence of this problem, and [Why are 'old' questions interweaved with 'new' ones?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193690/why-are-old-questions-interweaved-with-new-ones) for a new description of the problem.  There's no response from The Team yet to the new question; just speculation.  And the old one is from April 2013; it shouldn't still be relevant.

Comment: Dammit, it just happened again.  Sunday afternoon with the top five questions having questions asked 1 and 4 hours ago.  This stopped being interesting a while ago...