# Why are 'old' questions interweaved with 'new' ones?

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow, interesting-page

Here is a sample of what I've seen every so often for the last few days on Stack Overflow:

[image: Sample questions with odd modify times]

As you can see, the first three questions were recent — 1 and 4 minutes ago (though slightly less when I first loaded the page), but the fourth question was last modified 2 hours ago, then 6 minutes, then 4 hours ago, then 8 and 9 minutes ago.

Is this interweaving of 'old' questions with 'new' questions in the 'home' page intentional? (I am looking at the basic https://stackoverflow.com/ page.)  What is the rationale behind the revised ordering?

(I did look at the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) page and didn't see anything that looked relevant.)

---

About 4+ hours later:

[image]

Two of the questions in the older image are stuck in the newer image.

Comment: But it used to provide me with interesting questions in strictly chronological order — not in a mixed time order.  Something changed — I'd like to know what and why (before claiming it is a bug or something).

Comment: I noticed that this seems to be different a little while ago as well; in fact, there is a question that was last active 6 hours ago that's been in slot #2 every time I've visited [my main page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RF0K5.png) for the past hour or so -- that's not usual, even on a slow Saturday.

Comment: So I'm not the only one who's had this happen. I asked around when I noticed it and nobody else could reproduce it for themselves.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Ah, since I don't use the homepage these days I cannot comment on *that*.

Comment: Well, there goes my hypothesis that it only happened to users with two-word handles, the first word of which started with `J`, @Bolt.

Comment: Ok good someone else noticed. This was bothering me since Thursday I think. There was a couple of questions that would just not leave the home page that I've "accidentally" opened when looking for new questions... legitimately new questions never made it to the home page. Only going to the questions tab (then newest or active) would we be able to find them. Though at the time of this comment, it appears that the old questions are not showing on Stack Overflow home page anymore.

Comment: +1 This morning I noticed that my home page had new questions alternating with 10 hour old ones for the first 6 questions. It stuck like that for a couple of hours before sorting itself out.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Overmore your hypothesis can not be saved by allowing the first word to also start with a B, because with me they are ordered just fine.

Comment: As of this writing, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284094/running-two-bash-files-in-one-code) has been stuck in second place on the front page for at least four hours.

Comment: I've been seeing this all day. I don't know if this is related or not, but SO also seems to have a two second delay before loading. Meta loads fine, as do all the other sites I'm visiting.

Comment: @hjpotter92: That was in early April — they might, I suppose, be doing another experiment, but it shouldn't be the same experiment.  It would also be courteous to let us know when it they're messing around with the behaviour of important pages.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see a pattern and have a couple of theories. Of the "old" questions that I'm seeing in my view, 3 of the tags on the questions are listed as my favorites and they seem to be in fixed positions of the list (slot 2 and 4). I guess the "experiment" is to ensure that at least a few of your "_really_ favorite" questions on the homepage, but are at least X hours old. Either to get more exposure on questions that were asked a while ago but bumped off the homepage and possibly get you to answer or see something you otherwise might have missed.

Comment: @JeffMercado: It could be vaguely related to that. I edited the question 'Very short code, but, failed to release memory' and decided long ago that I was done with it. The 'Function Pointer Memory Pointer in C' question is one I answered — along with a number of others.  I've edited and answered 'Variable valued contaied within a fuction in Python' (to 'Variable value contained within a function in Python'), but that's dropped off my list anyway.  Dunno; there's some sort of rhyme or reason, but you can see from the background that they're all within one of my 'favourite' tags.  It's puzzling.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is the homepage loading much slower for you? There is initial delay of 2 seconds that wasn't there before, for me.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I've not noticed it as a specific two second delay, but there's a slightly sluggish feel to the page, too.  Borderline; I'd not call it out unless prodded.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler hmm, maybe location related. Hope they'll fix it soon anyway.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Now that you mention it, there is a noticeable delay when loading the homepage for me. Going to the questions view has no delay in comparison (loads practically instantly).

Comment: @Jeff thanks for confirming, let us all wish [good luck to Ben](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174679/so-cache-going-nuts-or-do-i-need-a-lot-of-sleep/174681?noredirect=1#comment607402_174681) in solving this! :)

Comment: I have one question stuck on the front page for 4 hours. It even has a tag that's on my ignore list so it's grayed out.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you still see it? I think they nuked it, at least for now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I got a faster response and strictly chronological order on the last refresh.

Comment: Cheers, let's hope it stay this way now. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It looks like the test is over for now. The old questions aren't mixed in and loading time of the home page is back to a respectable level of near-instant.