# Are topics suggested on the homepage based on user history?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, homepage

During the last semester, I had some Prolog courses and I look topics on StackOverflow to help me during my praticals work. I have noticed that SO shows on the homepage more and more questions about [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog). The same behaviour occurred with [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) (I had a project with this too), but it's less dramatic.

My question is simple: does StackOverflow (and SE sites in general) show questions on the home page according to a user's visit history, in addition to favorite tags?  I never answered any questions about prolog or wpf, so I don't think it came from my answers and I never saw a prolog question on my homepage before.

Comment: Good to know. So I have some luck with the 10% random to get prolog question. This is what it means?

Comment: If you don't have prolog as favorite then either luck or maybe the team did change the algorithm without telling anyone just yet. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes these tags factor in.  One of the very few things we log is which tags you tend to view and use that in some of our suggestions, including the home page.

...sometimes I kinda wish we didn't, it's a damn huge set in redis.

Data Porn time!  These 2 key patterns eat 1,540,240 keys and 1,439,674,632 bytes as of this answer, in case anyone's curious.  Our biggest redis data user is miniprofiler at 1,957,399,494 bytes (we started recording profiles for random requests a while back).

That's out of a total 18.2 GB used on the instance, which does about a billion ops a day.

Hmm, I guess I could do a blog post just on how we abuse the crap out of redis.  This totally went sideways from answering your question, oh well.

Comment: Eheh, always a problem to log visits on a popular site :D Thanks!

Comment: Always a pleasure to read this kind of answers! ;)