# How does Stack Exchange use MiniProfiler for recording profiles?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I notice that at this post [Are topics suggested on the homepage based on user history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217016/are-topics-suggested-on-the-homepage-based-on-user-history/217018#217018) @nick-craver said "we started recording profiles for random requests a while back".

I want to know more details about that, because I'm trying to use MiniProfiler for profiling every request and record them for analysis.

My application has some random performance issues, so I want to record every request and try to find out what happen when some requests go slow.

I'm want to record MiniProfiler results to a queue (in-memory, RabbitMQ, Redis, etc.) by implementing the StackExchange.Profiling.Storage.IStorage interface, log and analyse them. And I think the overhead of profiling every request should be acceptable. (I expect it would add less than 10 ms response time to every request and most requests will take at least 500 ms. I will run some performance test to ensure that.)